# ¿Cómo puedo reemplazar ciertos caracteres por otros de una lista?

Tags: python

Intento reemplazar ciertos caracteres de una lista por otros, mediante un ciclo `for`.

Tengo esta operación algebraica: `3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1` y quiero convertirlo a esto: `3a+2b³+3b²-1`

De la siguiente forma elimino los caracteres que no quiero, por ejemplo:

```
almacenado=[]
string = str(almacenado)
caracteres = "',[] " #Son los caracteres que se eliminan

for i in range(len(caracteres)):
    string = string.replace(caracteres[i],"")
```

Pero en este caso quiero reemplazar las potencias y las multiplicaciones por lo siguiente:

```
** 2 = ²
** 3 = ³
```

En el caso de las multiplicaciones, como son el mismo carácter `*` no sé como indicar para discernir entre la operación de potencia y la de multiplicación. En este caso quiero eliminar el operador `*`, pero sin afectar la operación de potencia.

Y así sucesivamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? De antemano muchas gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y aquí viene `maketrans` al rescate, este método en conjunto con `translate` permite cambiar una serie de caracteres de una cadena por otra, esto es muy utilizado cuando se quiere usar subíndices o superíndices, lastimosamente para este caso también usé expresiones regulares para hacer el trabajo mucho más fácil.

Por cierto no le veo sentido a esto `string = str(almacenado)`, si quieres convertir una lista a string simplemente usa el método `.join()` o itera sobre la propia lista.

Partiendo de un escenario así `3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1`.

```py
import re

regex = re.compile("\*\*[0-9]+") #creamos nuestra exxpresión regular
SUP = str.maketrans("0123456789","⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹") #establecemos los superindices

operacion = "3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1" #nuestro string

#buscamos las potencias
potencias = regex.findall(operacion)

#iteramos y reemplazamos
for op in potencias:
    operacion = operacion.replace(op, op[2:].translate(SUP))

print(operacion)
```

El truco está en el `for` donde iteramos en la lista de `potencias` que tiene todas las coincidencias y reemplazamos esa cadena por otra con los superíndices, esto se hace aplicando el método `translate`, ponemos `op[2:]` para omitir los 2 primeros caracteres que son los asteriscos quedando de esta forma solo el número como superíndice.

**Resultado**

```
3*a+2*b³+3*b²-1
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Opción 1: Usando ciclo while

Podrías ejecutar un ciclo while mientras existan '**', luego para cada uno de ellos los eliminas pero transformando el siguiente caracter con 'maketrans'.

*Solo funciona para potencias de un solo dígito, es posible extender usando un while .isnumeric()... translate*

```py
text="3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1"

trantab = str.maketrans("0123456789","⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹")

while '**' in text:
    index=text.index('**')
    text=text[:index]+text[index+2].translate(trantab)+text[index+3:]

print(text)
```

output:

`3*a+2*b³+3*b²-1`

##### Opción 2: Usando Regex

```py
text="3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1"

import re
trantab = str.maketrans("0123456789","⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹")

result=re.sub(r"(?<=[*][*])(\d+)",lambda p: p.group(1).translate(trantab),text)
print(result)
```

###### Explicación

El regex consiste en un 'positive look behind' (buscar caracter precedido de...) de '**' y una agrupación (\g<1>) que atrapa la potencia.
Tiene una función lambda que toma esa potencia 'p.group(1)' y la traslada de números enteros a supe-índice.

output:

`3*a+2*b³+3*b²-1`

##### Opción 3: Como has intuído

Como has intuido también puedes hacerlo remplazando directamente "**2":

```py
text="3*a+2*b**3+3*b**2-1"
text=text.replace("**2","²")
print(text)
```

output:

`3*a+2*b**3+3*b²-1`

Se tendría que repetir el proceso para cada caso partícular, notece que '**3' no ha sido remplazado. *Podría ser usando un ciclo while similar a la primera opción*